# How to add a tablesorter plugin to backboneJs

Tags: backbone.js, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter plugin that i want to implement in backbonejs. im using this in view.js

EDIT on list view :

```
   var AccountList = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){

},

        el:"#sub-account-list", 

        render: function(id){

            var self = this;
            var accountList = new SubAccountCollection([],{ id: id });

            accountList.fetch({

                success: function(accountLists){

                    var data = accountLists.toJSON();
                    var accounts = data[0].data.items;

                    var template = _.template(tmpl, {accounts:accounts});
                    self.$el.html(template)
                                          $(function(){
                        $('.tablesorter').tablesorter();

                    });

                },

            });

        }

    });

       }
```

My underscore template:
EDIT on the underscore template:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Name</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
        <tbody>

    <% _.each(accounts, function(account) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= (account.active == 'true') ? 'Inactive': 'Active' %></td>
                <td><%= account.name%></td>

            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But im getting no luck in sorting my table list. What im i doing wrong here?
Please any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: above is the added html.Thanks

Comment: why aren't you using `this.$el`?

Comment: i know i should be ideally, but i got a 'null' on running self.$el instead showing the "sub-account-list" div. Above is how i tried using the view list.

Comment: use `el:$("#sub-account-list"), ` then the `this.$el` will be available

Comment: something like the one i edited above?

Comment: is `template` generate correct table?

Comment: i still get "undefined",on running "self.el",  even after adding the el:$("#sub-account-list"), :(

Comment: yes, it does display correct table. i did a $('.tablesorter').html() and it did display.

Comment: Are you running your code when the DOM is ready?

Comment: when i run, $('#sub-account-list').html(), it displayes the table, however when i run the "this.el", it gives me null...:(

Comment: i just used the '$('#sub-account-list').html()' as a workaround to display my table. does it relate to displaying the "tablesorter" plugin? im sorry if im asking dumb questions. this is just my start on working with backbone..:(

Comment: @Nicolai: it worked!!!after adding the <thead> and <tr> it worked fine!. That was what i was missing..:) Thanks for the tip..